# How to get the username from HTML form to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm trying to get the user enter a username and access that value from a separate js file. The page redirects from one html to another after the user enters the name in the server (python) code. Is it causing the issue? Because, no matter what method (name, id, form, input field) I try it doesn't work. If I run the script from within the html file then I'm able to access it. Any help is appreciated!

```
const userStore = window.localStorage;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    // Connect to websocket
    var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

    if (!userStore.getItem('username')){
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            document.querySelector('#username').onsubmit = function() {
                const name = document.querySelector('#username').value;
                alert(`Welcome back ${name}!`);
            };
        });
    } else {
        userStore.setItem('username', document.querySelector("#username"));
    }

{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
Title
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

<section id="cover" class="min-vh-100">
    <div id="cover-caption">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-white">
                <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 mx-auto text-center form p-4">
                    <h1 class="display-4 py-2">Enter your Username.</h1>
                    <div class="px-2">
                        <form id="form" action="/flackchat" method="POST" class="justify-content-center">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="sr-only">Name</label>
                                <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Continue</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `document.querySelector("#username")` is an Element. You want `document.querySelector("#username").value`. Why do `'DOMContentLoaded'` twice? Should just use `addEventListener('load', ()=>{ /* code here */});` anyways. You should pass the EventObject to your submit function if `username` is really your form `id` *(seems odd)* then `EventObject.preventDefault();` so your page doesn't reload.

Comment: can you also post your html as well  there is the id #username exactly in the form ? (in from tag or input tag)\

Comment: Thank you @StackSlave and LogicBlower I went and changed the form id and the JS code based on my understanding of what you asked me to do, I put in some logto see what is happening. uploaded the files in github as it's too long for the comment here. [github](https://github.com/rajacs50/stackexchange.git) 

I see the userstore seems to have a username value, but it shows empty, the else block executes. I can see the username from the post method in my python print as well. I'm very new to this, so please let me know if you need more info etc... And thank you again for helping me with this!

Comment: Not too familiar with the syntax you're using to fetch the value of the username. The way I know it with vanilla JavaScript (which seems to be what you're using) is this way: `document.getElementById("username").value;`. Since you also mention that the JavaScript code works inside the HTML file itself, but not when you include it could mean that you are coming at it the wrong way. Try including it at the bottom of your application. If you need to do in another manner, it's about an export / import functionality, which you can Google based off your chosen language.

Comment: You also seem to not close your function properly, which causes an unexpected end of input error, but I assume that you are not running into that issue since you're completely ignoring the fact, so I just assume it's a minor error from copy pasting, which isn't really of any real concern. Either way I'll mention it. You're missing `});` to close your function properly.

Comment: Also edit your question to include all the relevant HTML code as well for future references (and not as a comment) - that's what @LogicBlower was requesting. Having to bounce off-site for HTML code simply isn't ideal.

Comment: Thank you @Martin, I wasn't sure if it's conventional to edit the original question :) I added the html part as well. Yes, when I don't close the func I get error and I fixed it in the code. I'm using vanilla JS, it extends from a layout page, I'll put the script tag at the bottom. I'll come back after trying your suggestions.

Comment: I included the script tag at the bottom with the same result!